# Cannot get analytics for google url shortener on some of my links

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I've got several links by google shortener and I am unable to access the analytics for one of them.
When I click on the first two analytics links it shows a 200 http status and the analytics show but with the last one there's a 500 error in my firefox console and the message *Short URL goo.gl/6PL9Fx not found* appears in a little message box.

Same thing with the [Google URL Shortener api reference](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/get). Whenever I try this api it gives me this as a response:

```
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

These are my links:

goo.gl/SBGshX

goo.gl/ExkDyv

goo.gl/6PL9Fx

I actually have more links than just these and there's another broken one but I didn't want to overload the question.

Comment: Some of my other links have stopped showing analytics now. It looks like they're going away one by one...

Comment: Now some of the information is available again via the api reference page. Hopefully it's just a temporary outage but having something from google go down like this without explanation (the blog states that support is ending today but it will work until 2019) is definitely not ideal.